# can't build Xcode app after ios upgrade 16.5.1

Tags: flutter, xcode

since I upgrade iOS app, I can't run my flutter on my iOS device or on an simulator

I have this error on simulator

```
This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install XXXXXX /Users/XXXXX/AndroidStudioProjects/XXXX/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

and this error on physical device

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a 
Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
```

when I look errors on xcode I have

```
 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Here is my flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Provisioning profil is valid

Even If i create a new flutter projet I have these errors on physical device. I succcessed to run simulator with new projet. I don't understand why old app who work before, not work today after upgrade. All information on Xcode are same between old projet and new. But on old I can't run simulator and new I can't and both I can't run physical device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ios upgrade you also need to update XCode to a newer version. In my case, after upgrading XCode to version 14.3.1, debugging on the phone started working again